# Find single exon models that are part of a multi exon gene

Tags: r, model, statistics, subset, bioinformatics

I have sets of models which includes single exon models and multi exon models (.psl). I have to find single exon models which are part of multi exon models

```
names(a)
[1] "qseqid"    "a_stitle"  "a_qlen"    "a_slen"    "a_length"  "a_qstart"  "a_qend"    "a_sstart" "a_send"    "a_evalue"  "a_pident"  "a_qcovs"   "a_qcovhsp"
```

How to write a code to compare sstart and send of models?

Expected output (data frame):

```
Mult_model      Sing_models
m_qseqid_1      s_qseqid_1, s_qseqid_2 ...
m_qseqid_2      s_qseqid_3
m_qseqid_3      s_qseqid_4, s_qseqid_5 ...
```

Comment: Question is not clear. What is the expected output?

Comment: Sorry :(
Expected output is the frame with the following collumns:
1 - qseqid of multi exon model,
2 - qseqid of single exon model(s) which are part of the multi exon model

Comment: Because `qsqid` has no "_"? Try `a[, grep("_", a, fixed = TRUE, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)]`.